# Get ID from PHP loop and use in a MYSQL query in a bootstrap modal

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have a php loop which gathers all data from a mysql table and displays it in a html table. within that table each row has a details button'

When a user clicks the details button a modal appears.

Here is my code

```
<table id="open" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
<thead>
   <tr>
      <th style="text-align: center;">Job Title</th>
      <th style="text-align: center;">Assigned To</th>
      <th style="text-align: center;">Name Or Class</th>
      <th style="text-align: center;">Priority</th>
      <th style="text-align: center;">Date</th>
      <th style="text-align: center;">Added By</th>
      <th style="text-align: center;">Days Open</th>
      <th style="text-align: center;">Replies</th>
      <th style="text-align: center;">Actions</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php 
    $getopenjobs = mysql_query("SELECT support.id, support.title, support.description, departments.name, support.assigned_to, support.name_class, support.priority, support.datetime, users.firstname, users.lastname, support.status, COUNT(support_replies.job_id) AS replies, DATEDIFF(CURDATE(), support.datetime) as 'difference', support_replies.reply
                FROM support JOIN departments ON support.assigned_to = departments.id JOIN users ON support.added_by = users.id LEFT JOIN support_replies ON support.id = support_replies.job_id WHERE support.status ='1' GROUP BY id");
    $count = 0;
    echo '<tr>';
    if (mysql_num_rows($getopenjobs) == 0) {  
       echo '<td colspan="9">No Open Jobs Found</td>'; 
    } else {
       while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($getopenjobs))
       {
            echo '<td style="';

            if($row['assigned_to'] == '1') {
                echo 'background: #00C0EF; ';
            }

            if($row['assigned_to'] == '2') {
                echo 'background: #F39C12; ';
            }

            if($row['assigned_to'] == '3') {
                echo 'background: #00A65A; ';
            }

            if($row['assigned_to'] == '4') {
                echo 'background: #F56954; ';
            }

            echo 'text-align: left;">' . $row['title'] . '</td>';
            echo '<td style="';

            if($row['assigned_to'] == '1') {
                echo 'background: #00C0EF; ';
            }

            if($row['assigned_to'] == '2') {
                echo 'background: #F39C12; ';
            }

            if($row['assigned_to'] == '3') {
                echo 'background: #00A65A; ';
            }

            if($row['assigned_to'] == '4') {
                echo 'background: #F56954; ';
            }


            echo 'text-align: center;">' . $row['name'] . '</td>';

            echo '<td style="';

            if($row['assigned_to'] == '1') {
                echo 'background: #00C0EF; ';
            }

            if($row['assigned_to'] == '2') {
                echo 'background: #F39C12; ';
            }

            if($row['assigned_to'] == '3') {
                echo 'background: #00A65A; ';
            }

            if($row['assigned_to'] == '4') {
                echo 'background: #F56954; ';
            }


            echo 'text-align: center;">' . $row['name_class'] . '</td>';

            echo '<td style="';

            if($row['assigned_to'] == '1') {
                echo 'background: #00C0EF; ';
            }

            if($row['assigned_to'] == '2') {
                echo 'background: #F39C12; ';
            }

            if($row['assigned_to'] == '3') {
                echo 'background: #00A65A; ';
            }

            if($row['assigned_to'] == '4') {
                echo 'background: #F56954; ';
            }

            echo 'text-align: center;">';

            if($row['priority'] == '1') {
                echo 'Low';
            }

            if($row['priority'] == '2') {
                echo 'Medium';
            }

            if($row['priority'] == '3') {
                echo '
                High';
            }

            if($row['priority'] == '4') {
                echo '
                Very High';
            }

            if($row['priority'] == '5') {
                echo '
                Critical';
            }
            echo '<td style="';

            if($row['assigned_to'] == '1') {
                echo '
                background: #00C0EF; ';
            }

            if($row['assigned_to'] == '2') {
                echo '
                background: #F39C12; ';
            }

            if($row['assigned_to'] == '3') {
                echo '
                background: #00A65A; ';
            }

            if($row['assigned_to'] == '4') {
                echo '
                background: #F56954; ';
            }


            echo 'text-align: center;">' . $row['datetime'] . '</td>';

            echo '<td style="';

            if($row['assigned_to'] == '1') {
                echo '
                background: #00C0EF; ';
            }

            if($row['assigned_to'] == '2') {
                echo '
                background: #F39C12; ';
            }

            if($row['assigned_to'] == '3') {
                echo '
                background: #00A65A; ';
            }

            if($row['assigned_to'] == '4') {
                echo '
                background: #F56954; ';
            }


            echo 'text-align: center;">' . $row['firstname'] . ' ' . $row['lastname'] . '</td>';

            echo '<td style="';

            if($row['assigned_to'] == '1') {
                echo '
                background: #00C0EF; ';
            }

            if($row['assigned_to'] == '2') {
                echo '
                background: #F39C12; ';
            }

            if($row['assigned_to'] == '3') {
                echo '
                background: #00A65A; ';
            }

            if($row['assigned_to'] == '4') {
                echo '
                background: #F56954; ';
            }


            echo 'text-align: center;"><span style="color: black;" class="step">' . $row['difference'] . '</span></td>';

            echo '<td style="';

            if($row['assigned_to'] == '1') {
                echo '
                background: #00C0EF; ';
            }

            if($row['assigned_to'] == '2') {
                echo '
                background: #F39C12; ';
            }

            if($row['assigned_to'] == '3') {
                echo '
                background: #00A65A; ';
            }

            if($row['assigned_to'] == '4') {
                echo '
                background: #F56954; ';
            }


            echo 'text-align: center;"><span style="color: black;" class="step">' . $row['replies'] . '</span></td>';

            echo '<td style="';

            if($row['assigned_to'] == '1') {
                echo '
                background: #00C0EF; ';
            }


            if($row['assigned_to'] == '2') {
                echo '
                background: #F39C12; ';
            }

            if($row['assigned_to'] == '3') {
                echo '
                background: #00A65A; ';
            }

            if($row['assigned_to'] == '4') {
                echo '
                background: #F56954; ';
            }


            echo 'text-align: center;"><a data-datetime="' . 
                 $row['datetime'] . '" data-recipientname="' . 
                 $row['firstname'] . ' ' . $row['lastname'] . '" 
                 data-id="' . $row['id'] . '" data-title="' . 
                 $row['title'] . '" data-desc="' . $row['description'] . 
                 '" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#details" 
                 class="open-details btn btn-primary btn-sm">Details</a> </td>';
            echo '</tr>';
            $count++;
            }


            echo '<div class="modal fade" id="details" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                  <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                      <div class="modal-body">
                        <!-- Chat box -->
                        <div class="box-body chat" id="chat-box">


            <!--JOB -->
            <div style="position: left; width: 80%; background: #F2DEDE; border: 1px solid #A94442; border-radius: 8px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px;" class="item">
               <img src="img/avatar-placeholder.png" alt="user image"/>
               <p class="message">
                  <a href="#" class="name">
                     <small class="time text-muted pull-right"><i  class="fa fa-clock-o"></i></small>
                    <p class="recipientname"></p>
                  </a>
                  <p class="title"></p></br>

                  <p class="description"></p>
                </p>
             </div><!-- /.JOB -->';

    $query = ("SELECT support_replies.reply, support_replies.datetime, 
                      users.firstname, users.lastname 
               FROM support_replies 
                 JOIN users on support_replies.added_by = users.id 
               WHERE support_replies.job_id = '" . $row['id'] . "' 
               ORDER BY support_replies.id DESC");
    $row =  mysql_query($query);    
    while( false !== ($replies = mysql_fetch_assoc($row)))
    {
        echo '<ul style="list-style:none; margin-left: 0; padding-left: 0;">';
        echo '<li>';

        echo '<div style="width: 80%; background: #DFF0D8; border: 1px solid #46763D; border-radius: 8px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px; padding-top: 10px; margin-left: 20%;" class="item">
               <img src="img/avatar-placeholder.png" alt="user image"/>
               <p class="message">
                  <a href="#" class="name">
                      <small class="text-muted pull-right"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> ' . $replies['datetime'] . '</small>
                      ' . $replies['firstname'] . ' ' . $replies['lastname'] . '
                  </a>
                  ' . $replies['reply'] . '
                </p>
                </div><!-- /.item -->';

            echo '</li>';
            echo '</ul>';
        }   
        echo  '</div><!-- /.chat -->
               <div class="box-footer">
                  <div class="input-group">
                      <input class="form-control" placeholder="Type reply ..."/>
                       <div class="input-group-btn">
                            <button class="btn btn-success"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i></button>
                       </div>
                  </div></div>
                </div>
              </div>
        </div>
     </div>';
    }
?>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th style="text-align: center;">Job Title</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;">Assigned To</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;">Name Or Class</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;">Priority</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;">Date</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;">Added By</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;">Days Open</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;">Replies</th>
        <th style="text-align: center;">Actions</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
```

I want to be able to get the ID of the current table row where the user has clicked on the details button and use the ID within the modal, I want to run another MYSQL query within the modal and use the ID as the MYSQL WHERE.

For example

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE ID = "HERE WILL GO THE ID PULLED THROUGH"
```

I know that it is possible to pass through the data and just display it as I have already done this, but I dont want to display it i want to use it within a new mysql query.

How can I get a list of all replies within the model based on the table row ID

Comment: Next time edit your code so it can be read without scrolling left and right. And did we need this much code!

Answer (score 0):

You could write this so that clicking on the Details button triggers an ajax call to fetch a separate page e.g. `/some/other/page?id=XXXX`.

On that separate page you run your query with the ID that was passed in and then return the content (HTML/JSON etc.) and display it in the modal.

Comment: Could you post an example?

Comment: In your code you do `<a ... data-toggle="modal" data-target="#details" ...>Details</a>`, if you just add the href attribute to that e.g. `<a href="/some/other/page?id=XXXX" ... data-toggle="modal" data-target="#details" ...>Details</a>` then the content of the other page should be loaded. As I said before your separate page can do whatever (e.g. run your SELECT query) before returning the content.

Comment: I have done it :) Thanks you, i wouldnt of done it without you.